# Equivalence Relation, and finding the subset that defines the relation.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x\sim y$ means $xy >  0$. Prove this is an equivalence relation. Find the subset of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ which defines the relation. Find the equivalence classes.

$x\sim y \Leftrightarrow xy >  0$ is an equivalence relation since it is:

1) Reflexive: $x\sim x$ since $x\times x > 0$, that is $x^{2} > 0$, which is trivially true.

2) Symmetric: If $x\sim y$ such that $xy > 0$ and $yx > 0$, we know that $xy > 0$ will be positive so either $x > 0$ and $y > 0$ or $x < 0$ and $y < 0$ since $xy > 0$ will be positive so will $yx > 0$.

3) Transitive: $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$ implies $x\sim z$: $xy > 0$ and $yz > 0$ where $z$ is an integer.  Since, $(xy)(yz) > 0$ then $xy^{2}z > 0$ since $y^{2}$ is strictly positive for any $y$, $xz > 0$.

I am not sure if this is right, and I am confused about finding the subset and the equivalence classes, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might think about streamlining your argument for 2).

Comment: As for finding the equivalence classes ---- start by picking a particular $x$ --- say $x=1$ --- and figure out the equivalence class it belongs to.

Comment: A question to ask yourself: does there exist $x \in \Bbb R$ such that $x \sim 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly right, which means wrong.

The Transitive proof is correct.

The symmetric proof is correct, but cluttered.  You just have to say that: as multiplication of reals is commutative, then $xy>0$ implies $yx>0$.

However, the reflexive proof is wrong.   It ignores the case of $x=0$.   $0\sim 0$ is `false` because $0\times 0 \not> 0$.

Thus the relation is not an equivalence relation for $\Bbb R$.  It is only an equivalence relation for $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

In such case, the equivalence classes of $x\in \Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ are:

$$[x] \mathop{:=}\{y\in\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}: xy>0\}$$

Can you now identify both of them?

Comment: Reading from the question, you should find a subset of $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ for which it is a equivalence relation.

Comment: so what would be the subset that defines the relation?